# attach bullets to slider images

Tags: jquery

I have set up a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/K8aex/

I need the bullets to move the slides also
I am trying to attach the click of the bullet to the index of the relevant slide 
How would I do this? find the index of the bullet the find the index of the img with same index? make that one the current slide?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
   $('.bullets a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var bulletIndex = (this).index()
        console.log(bulletIndex)
        wrapper.find('li:nth-child(bulletIndex) img').addClass('current');

    });
```

Thanks

Comment: The jsFiddle is nice, but you should also include the relevant code in your question so we have the context here in SO.

Comment: I think you put her the *relevant* code, not *all the* code.

Comment: ok sorry I don't use stackoverflow that much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd make abstraction functions to slide to a specific image like, where you set your properties and make your animations:

```
function slideTo(i) {
    ...
}
```

You've already implemented it, but it's pretty scattered through your code.

Your provided click handler also has some errors, this is a cleaned up version:

```
$('.bullets a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var bulletIndex = $(this).text();
    slideTo(bulletIndex);
});
```